# Writing a parallel quick sort in c

Tags: c, data-structures, pthreads, quicksort

I need to write a parallel quick sort in c using pthreads. This is what I did so far.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <unistd.h>  // sleep()
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_SUCCESS
    #include <string.h>  // strerror()
    #include <errno.h>

    #define SIZE_OF_DATASET 6
    void* quickSort( void* data);
    int partition( int* a, int, int);


    struct info {
        int start_index;
        int* data_set;
        int end_index;
    };



    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

        int a[] = { 7, 12, 1, -2,8,2};
        pthread_t thread_id;
        struct info *info = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
        info->data_set=malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE_OF_DATASET);

        info->data_set=a;
        info->start_index=0;
        info->end_index=SIZE_OF_DATASET-1;

        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, quickSort, info)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);

        printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
        int i;
          for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_DATASET; ++i)
               printf(" %d ", info->data_set[i]);

        return 0;
    }

    void* quickSort( void *data)
    {
        struct info *info = data;
        int j,l,r;
        l = info->start_index;
        r = info->end_index;

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_t thread_id1;
        pthread_t thread_id2;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);

       if( l < r )
       {

           j = partition( info->data_set, l, r);
           info->start_index=l;
           info->end_index=j-1;
           if(info->end_index<0)info->end_index=0;

          if (pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, quickSort, info)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
                return NULL;
          }
          info->start_index=j+1;
          info->end_index=r;

          if (pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, quickSort, info)) {
              fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
              return NULL;
          }

          pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);
          pthread_join(thread_id2, NULL);
      }

    return NULL;

    }


    int partition( int* a, int l, int r) {
       int pivot, i, j, t;
       pivot = a[l];
       i = l; j = r+1;

       while( 1)
       {
        do ++i; while( a[i] <= pivot && i <= r );
        do --j; while( a[j] > pivot );
        if( i >= j ) break;
        t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
       }
       t = a[l]; a[l] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
       return j;
    }
```

But inside quick sort function only call first thread only. Cant understand what is been happening here.

Note : serial version of code has been tested. no issue with that

**UPDATE:**

This is modified version based on John Bollinger's solution. But still second half of array which is taken by newly created thread inside quicksort is not sorted.

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int a[] = { 7, 12, 1, -2, 0, 15, 4, 11, 9,5,3,24,5,23,3,1,56,8,4,34,23,51};
    struct info *info = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    info->data_set=malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE_OF_DATASET);
    info->data_set=a;
    info->start_index=0;
    info->end_index=SIZE_OF_DATASET-1;

    quickSort(info);
    printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
    int i;
      for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_DATASET; ++i)
           printf(" %d ", info->data_set[i]);
    return 0;
}

void* quickSort( void *data)
{
    struct info *info = data;
    struct info *info1 = data;
    int j,l,r;
    l = info->start_index;
    r = info->end_index;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread_id1;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

   if( l < r )
   {

       j = partition( info->data_set, l, r);
       info1->start_index=j+1;
       info1->end_index=r;
       info1->data_set = info->data_set;
       if(info1->end_index<0)info1->end_index=0;

      if (pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, quickSort, info1)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
            return NULL;
      }
      info->start_index=l;
      info->end_index=j-1;

      if(info->end_index < 0) info->end_index = 0;
      quickSort(info);  /* don't care about the return value */
      pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);

  }

return NULL;

}
```

Comment: Make a copy of `info` instead of modifying the same pointer everywhere.

Comment: then array which store data has to synchronized. is it  a good way to do this ?

Comment: compiler says something like `control reaches end of non-void function` and `warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void` in quickSort.

Comment: @mch corrected that mistake sorry for that because I didn't  compile with -Wall  flag

Comment: You're sharing the same `struct info` between threads. You need separate start and end index variables for each thread. Also, `return 0;` in `quickSort`.

Comment: @molbdnilo It did not work for me. I tried using difference strct for two threads. then shared array no longer there. Each time they create new struct and continuous. so can we do this using two struct.

Comment: Note that you create about twice as many threads as you need.  Function `quickSort()` does not need to create *two* threads, because it's already running in one perfectly good one.  It can instead create just one new thread in which to handle one sub-array, and handle the other sub-array in the current thread.

Comment: Similarly, it doesn't do you much good to create a thread in `main()` in which to run the top-most `quickSort()` call, when the main thread isn't going to do anything but wait on that thread anyway.

Comment: @John I did the same thing what you suggest. but no lock. You mean instead of creating new thread I tried to use   quickSort(&info)  but I got same result ?

Comment: @GPrathap, my comments refer to a side issue, not to the correctness of your program.  On the other hand, two or more concurrent threads sharing the same info structure absolutely *is* a correctness issue when one or both of them modify that structure, as in this case they do.

Comment: @John I am really tired on this. can you give some example code how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89603/discussion-between-gprathap-and-john-bollinger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is incorrect because your threads all share the same `struct info` structure describing the sub-problem they are supposed to be working on.  They run concurrently (or may do, anyway) and they modify that structure as they proceed, so the values that any particular thread sees are indeterminate.

To resolve this, each `quickSort` frame must create at least one new `struct info`, so that the two `quickSort()` calls it makes in different threads each has its own.  As a matter of efficiency, it would also be better to spawn only one additional thread in each `quickSort()` call.  For example:

```
void* quickSort( void *data)
{
    struct info *info = data;
    struct info other_info;

    /* ... */

        /* launch a new thread to handle one partition: */
        other_info.start_index = j + 1;
        other_info.end_index = r;
        other_info.data_set = info->data_set;
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, quickSort, &other_info)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No threads for you.\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        /* handle the other partition in the current thread: */
        info->start_index = l;
        info->end_index = j - 1;
        if(info->end_index < 0) info->end_index = 0;
        quickSort(info);  /* don't care about the return value */

        /* after this thread is done, wait for the other thread to finish, too */
        pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);

    /* ... */
}
```

Note that this does not ensure that any particular pair of threads runs concurrently, neither in a multi-core sense nor in a time-slicing sense.  That's up to the OS.  Certainly, however, the multi-core sense of parallelism applies only where there are in fact multiple cores available on the host machine on which the OS is willing to schedule your process.

Comment: Still I am getting second half of array as unsorted. Which mean there something wrong with newly created thread which is inside quicksort. Because main thread works on first part of the array and second part of array is worked in newly created thread. aren't you getting such error when array size is increasing ?

Comment: @GPrathap, the program, modified as I described, is producing correctly-sorted output for me.  It still produced correctly-sorted output when I doubled the size of the input (though that's still a small input).  If you have a specific error case then present it.

Comment: I updated problem based on your solution. can you tell me now where when wrong. really appreciate what you have done so far. thank you so much

Comment: @GPrathap, your updated code *does not* correspond to my solution.  You created a new pointer variable `info1`, but you initialize it to point to the same underlying `struct info` that pointer `info` points to.  There is still only one `struct info` in use by all the threads in your revised program.

Comment: really sorry I made a mistake. Now everything is working fine. Thank you so mush for help me to get through this. I accepted the answer  you gave.